# Memory Leak when subclassing custom UIViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-leaks

I've been recently suffering a memory leak when profiling with instruments.

So the situation is I have a parent AVC which inherits from UIViewController and a subclass of AVC called BVC. this BVC has an instance of a helper class that gets initialized on viewDidLoad. Well, instruments claims there is a memory leak on viewDidLoad.

[image: Instruments output]

Here's the sample code I used to reproduce the problem. Weird thing is if "a" is a member of AVC and initialized in BVC "A" it does not leak.

```
import UIKit

class A
{
}

class AVC: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

class BVC: AVC
{
    var a: A!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        a = A()
    }
}
```

So the question is, why is "a" leaking when it is an instance of BVC and not AVC? Also, here's a capture of the memory graph in both cases.

[image: Memory graph]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a as

```
var a: A?
```

never used forced unbinding of optionals.

Comment: That's not the point at all and does not answer the question. Moreover in my actual app "a" should never be nil and I can't initialize it directly in the same line it is declared so the elegant solution is to force unwrap, it is one of the actual uses of force unwrapping.